# Tidy data, issue with gather()

Tags: r

I have the below data frame.
I was wondering, what is the best way to make this tidy so I can plot using ggplot2.
I've tried using the gather() function in R, to do something like this:

```r
tidy_cost <- gather(cost, key = 'Utility', value = 'unit', -c(Date, `Gas price`, `Electricity price`))
```

then:

```r
tidy_cost <- gather(tidy_cost, key = 'Price', value = 'GBP', -c(Date, Utility, unit))
```

but what the above does is dublicate everything as for some cells there is a missmatch between 'Utility' and 'Price'....see table 2. Any advice would be greately appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: Table snippet]

[image: Table2]

code to reproduce sample of original data frame :

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18686, 18714, 18745, 18775, 
18806), class = "Date"), `Gas usage` = c(0, 125, 104, 98, 43), 
    `Gas price` = c(0, 45.46, 39.67, 38.32, 19.18), `Electricity usage` = c(0, 
    208, 232, 226, 166), `Electricity price` = c(0, 37.82, 43.09, 
    42.98, 32.2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `gather` has been superseded for quite a while, I suggest shifting to `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans I tried using pivot_longer() but had similar results. Would you have any suggestions?  I've included the code above....sorry if this was done improperly. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I might have suggestions, but I'm not going to guess about the data, and I'm not going to transcribe from an image.

Comment: of course not, I'm sorry I thought it would be a straight forward solution, things rarely are. I cant get the formatting to look right, but the dput output is the below. Thank you for your help. 


    structure(list(Date = structure(c(18686, 18714, 18745, 18775, 
18806), class = "Date"), `Gas usage` = c(0, 125, 104, 98, 43), 
    `Gas price` = c(0, 45.46, 39.67, 38.32, 19.18), `Electricity usage` = c(0, 
    208, 232, 226, 166), `Electricity price` = c(0, 37.82, 43.09, 
    42.98, 32.2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're planning to come up with `GBP`, but is this what you're trying to do?

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(cost, -Date, names_pattern = "(.*) (.*)", names_to = c("Utility", ".value"))
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    Date       Utility     usage price
#    <date>     <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 2021-02-28 Gas             0   0  
#  2 2021-02-28 Electricity     0   0  
#  3 2021-03-28 Gas           125  45.5
#  4 2021-03-28 Electricity   208  37.8
#  5 2021-04-28 Gas           104  39.7
#  6 2021-04-28 Electricity   232  43.1
#  7 2021-05-28 Gas            98  38.3
#  8 2021-05-28 Electricity   226  43.0
#  9 2021-06-28 Gas            43  19.2
# 10 2021-06-28 Electricity   166  32.2
```

(I don't think `tidyr::gather` is going to be able to do this, one reason why it is superseded by `pivot_longer`.)